# MSBuild can't exec command `npm i` while compiling a project in Rider/Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, .net-5, visual-studio-mac, rider, msbuild-task

I need to build and run a .NET 5 project in Mac using Visual Studio for Mac or Jetbrains Rider.

In `csproj` file of one of the projects in the solution, I have following Target:

```
  <Target Name="SassBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Exec Command="npm i" />
    <Exec Command="npm rebuild node-sass" />
    <Exec Command="npm run gulp-sass" />
    <Exec Command="npm run gulp-js" />
  </Target>
```

When I run `dotnet build` or `dotnet msbuild` project builds just fine, however building it in VS/Rider throws the following error:

`Error MSB3073: The command "npm i" exited with code 127. (MSB3073)`

Details in the log:

```
Target SassBuild:
    npm i
    /var/folders/9l/d02_tk1j5f93vklft82p1z996dm09b/T/tmp89785a0aeebb4347a3696de11d8c281e.exec.cmd: line 2: npm: command not found
    PATH_TO_CSPROJ_HERE.csproj(232,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm i" exited with code 127.
Done building target "SassBuild" in project "X.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

`npm` is installed already and I can run the npm commands in terminal. I use `nvm` for node versioning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out that Mac OS terminal and VS/Rider terminals are not fed from the same terminal configuration files; that's why the IDEs weren't able to find the npm in their paths.

I copied all the `nvm` related configuration from `~/.zprofile` to `~/.profile` and now I am able to build the project in VS/Rider.

Hope it helps anyone having the same problem.

Comment: In the terminal window running `echo $SHELL` will display the current shell. In Rider's 'Preferences', in 'Tools -> Terminal' check if the shell path is set to bash. The default shell on macOS is zsh, and the .zprofile file is specific to zsh. My guess is your Rider preferences are set to bash.

Comment: It looks like Visual Studio uses the default login shell. You can change the default shell for your user account in `System Preferences -> Users & Groups`. Click the padlock icon to make changes. Then right-click on your user account and choose `Advanced Options...`.  (The popup menu will not appear if you haven't unlocked.) In Advanced Options, change the 'Login shell'. If Visual Studio was using bash and Terminal was using zsh, then in Terminal's Preferences under 'General', 'Shells open with' may have been explicitly set to zsh instead of 'Default login shell'.